# How to read return status of exe installed using MSI packaging?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, setup-deployment

I have created a msi using VS2010 Setup and Deployment template. In this I have referred a exe(Application) in Custom action->Install to be installed when MSI is executed . If the exe execution fails How do i read the failure status returned by MSI.

Note: the msi is pushed using Group policy so there will be NO user interaction.The MSI should fail and not appear in the control panel.

Answer (score 1):

Custom action return values cannot be handled.

A DLL custom action can use different return codes to trigger a specific behavior in the installer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369778(VS.85).aspx

An EXE custom action can only return 0 for success or any other value for failure.

So if your EXE returns a non-zero value when failing, the package will not be installed.

Comment: Thanks,
I am getting failure in installation dialog when returning "ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE" or "ERROR_INSTALL_USEREXIT" from EXE custom action.
But while pushing this package through User policy , the dialog box requires user interaction, which cannot be given hence the login process for that user is not completed.i.e it stays on Welcome page for long..
Is there any way I can bypass this dialog box with failure message?

Comment: Windows Installer automatically stops the installation when receiving these return values. When deploying the package through a network make sure that it uses a silent installation and not a full UI. For this you can set LIMITUI property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369759(VS.85).aspx?ppud=4